# Jquery Slide up Login form

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="divLogin">
<a> 
<img src="Image1.jpg" style="height:32px;padding-top:0px;" id="img"/></a>

<div id="subLogin" style="width:250px">        

    <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSend">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%" style="color: White">
                Username
            </td>
            <td width="3%">
                :
            </td>
            <td width="27%">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="color: White">
                Password
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <asp:Button Text="Send" runat="server" ID="btnSend" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</asp:Panel>

 </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divLogin > a").click(function () {

        $("#subLogin").slideToggle(400);
    });
});



$(document).click(function (e) {
    var elem = (e.target || e.srcElement).id;
    if (elem != 'img') {
        $("#subShare").slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

When I click on the image, I want to show the Login form through Jquery Slide. I want to Slideup the subLogin div on document click. The div is also sliding up when I click on the subLogin div or btnSend button.plz help...

**Updated:** Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WN2uB/

Comment: can u set up a fiddle link??

Comment: hi just check out the fiddle slidetoggel on img click..http://jsbin.com/ibamoWU/1/edit

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: The div is also sliding up when I click on the subLogin div or btnSend button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're going for?

http://jsfiddle.net/WN2uB/2/

```
 $(document).click(function (e) {
     if(!$(e.target).is("#img")&&!$.contains($("#subLogin")[0],e.target)) { 
         $("#subLogin").slideUp(400);
     }
 });
```